# How calculate tax on discounted product in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Example :

Product Price in magento MRP - USD 1000 which includes 10% GST

Now customer applied discount ie 50% off, the price is now 500$

Now i want to add 10% GST on 500 USD ie 50$ - so total would become - 550USD.

how to achieve this thing in magento?

Answer (score 0):

Refer backend setting in magento.

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Taxes > Calculation Settings > Apply Discount On Prices
```

Apply discount on price including tax is calculated based on store tax, if "Apply Tax after Discount" is selected.

Comment: This does not solve my problem. These settings are already applied. 

What i want to do is : I want to charge tax on product aftr discount.